# Node.js TypeError: res.json is not a function

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-editor

I am trying to create a simple hello world application using Swagger and Node.js that prints out "Hello, " when I call GET but I am getting the error: **TypeError: res.json is not a function**. Using the Swagger Editor, I created the following yaml api:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
 version: "1.0.0"
 title: "Hello World"
paths:
/hello:
 get:
  x-swagger-router-controller: "hello_world"
  description: "Returns 'Hello' to the caller"
  operationId: "hello"
  parameters:
  - name: "name"
    in: "query"
    description: "The name of the person to whom to say hello"
    required: false
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "Returns greeting"
      schema:
        type: "string"
        title: "HelloWorldResponse"
    400:
      description: "Invalid characters in \"user\" were provided"
definitions: {}
```

I used the swagger editor to generate a node.js server and created a hello_world.js controller. When I try to test the code using the Swagger UI by calling http://localhost:8081/hello?name=victory, I'm seeing the error: TypeError: res.json is not a function. Here is my node.js code:

```
'use strict';

var util = require('util');

module.exports = {
 hello: hello
};

function hello(req, res) {
// variables defined in the Swagger document can be referenced using  req.swagger.params.{parameter_name}
 var name = req.swagger.params.name.value || 'stranger';
 var greeting = util.format('Hello, %s!', name); 
 // this sends back a JSON response which is a single string
 res.json(greeting); //ERRORS OUT HERE
}
```

I'm new to Swagger and Node.js so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error or the best way to go about troubleshooting it. Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

UPDATE: It turns out that res.end(greeting) works. Can anyone explain why res.json and res.send don't?

Comment: I get TypeError: res.send is not a function when I change res.json(greeting); to res.send(greeting);

Comment: can you show how you use the `hello` controller?

Comment: I think the controller is getting used when I try out the Swagger API. The UI says that it is calling curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/html' 'http://localhost:8081/hello?name=bob'. Is there some other place it should be called or specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `json` function is added to the response object by express.js, but the swagger generator generates code which uses connect.js (not express).

Express is built on top of connect, and if you want features from express, you can easily use express in place of connect in the code generated by the swagger generator. Find the line in `index.js` which says `const app = require('connect')();`, and replace 'connect' with 'express'.

Comment: I found the documentation for the nodejs server from swagger stub woeful. It is needed mainly because JS functions are atrocious to figure out as their signature is not clear just by looking at the code, and it is even harder to follow code using tags. I think we could all use more documentation for what is being used by the swagger code so that we can make the correct guess. That said, your response is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use this

> 

```js
utils.writeJson(res, "sucess").end();
```

Comment: Can you also explain how this helps?